# Run Another Function When Any Command Is Called discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I need to run a common function whenever my discord bot commands are called! like the common function should execute first then it should run the command function
**EXAMPLE:**

```
async def common():
    #some code

@client.command()
async def something(ctx):
    #command code
```

So, When ever the `something()` function is called like `'!something'` by the user in discord, the `common()` function should execute first and then it should execute the `something()` function and in my bot i have tons of commands so i cant able to type  `common()` on top of every command functions!.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the `before_invoke` decorator on your common function. You can read more on it [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=on_command#discord.ext.commands.Bot.before_invoke).

```
@client.before_invoke
async def common(message):
    await message.channel.send("This is the common function")


@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("This is the test command")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is an event that is triggered everytime a command is executed: [**on_command**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=on_command#discord.on_command).

So if you wanted to run the common function when any command is called you could create an `on_command` event:

```
async def on_command(ctx):
    common() # execute common function
```

Comment: thank a lot man ! But i need to run the common function first and then it should execute the command function! but here both are executing at the same time! is there any function to stop the command function until the on_command function finish executing the code!

Comment: If you want to stop the command function until the event is done, you should use some shared state, to check whether your common function has been executed. This is something you need to add manually (afaik)

Comment: Dependant on what you want to do in your common function, there might be other ways to solve your problem.

Comment: Like I have a database to store some data's about the user, so I need to get some data from the database in that on_command function and make that data store in global variables. So after finishing these process in that on_command function . I will use the global variable which we stored from the database, I will use that in user called function.

Comment: You could possibly create a decorator, such that whenever something is called it does x before the command