# discord.py dm User when using the bot?

Tags: discord.py

I want to send to the user a change log message when someone uses the bot!
Is there something like on_command when someone uses the bot they get a dm?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run Another Function When Any Command Is Called discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64844786/run-another-function-when-any-command-is-called-discord-py)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use either [`before_invoke`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=invoke#discord.ext.commands.Bot.before_invoke) or [`after_invoke`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=invoke#discord.ext.commands.Bot.before_invoke) depending on when you want your log message to run.

```py
@client.before_invoke
async def before_invoke(ctx):
    await ctx.send('before invoke')
@client.after_invoke
async def after_invoke(ctx):
    await ctx.send('after invoke')
    await ctx.author.send('Command completed!')
```

Comment: Okay and how are this work in Cogs?

Comment: It applies *globally* to every command in the bot. However, you can also use `cog_before_invoke`/`cog_after_invoke` ([here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=cog#discord.ext.commands.Cog.cog_before_invoke)) at the cog level.